# two tomcat sharing the cache and supporting each other in failure situation

Tags: java, tomcat, caching

Please advise as I am stuck up with this following scenario that is let's say there is a client who sends the request to the Apache server.

On the other side there are two tomcat servers running parallel on different ports in the cluster, and on both the tomcat servers the same war file is deployed.

Now the problem is that let's say if the client sends the request to apache server and apache server sends the request to the first tomcat and in that first tomcat cache was written and then the first tomcat goes down after writing the cache.

And then comes the second request from a client which again goes to apache server and then apache server redirect it two-second tomcat since the first tomcat is down and it also sends the cache of the first tomcat to the second tomcat please advise how we can achieve this scenario,

The purpose is that I do not want the application to suffer even if the first tomcat goes down. and also I am looking for best clustering that can be happened in tomcat as I am expecting heavy traffic from the end client

Comment: Why not use distributed cache ?

Comment: Can you please share an example so that I can grasp more

Comment: What kind of cache are you talking about? I would find it unusual for a reverse-proxy to maintain a cache for an origin server by *sending the cache* to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at distributed caches. They solve this kind of challenges.

Options are:

- Ehcache/Terracotta
- Redis
- Memcached
- Hazelcast

[Bozho's tech blog](https://techblog.bozho.net/distributed-cache-overview/) has a good and current overview. You might want to read it.

**Update**

The challenge you are facing is that the cached data needs to be available to all Tomcat instances and that the cached data needs to stay consistent if it is modified and queried on several Tomcat instances.

That's exactly what these distributed caches provide:

1. They write modified data to a shared storage or send it to other instances so it will be available to other instances if needed.
2. They keep the distributed data consistent so that no Tomcat instance uses outdated data or modifies it in a way that would break consistency.

The distributed caches usually use a two stage concept where the some of the data is kept in memory and everything is persisted on disk.

So by using the distributed cahce, your second Tomcat instances can serve the clients of the first instance in case that instance goes down.

Comment: How they will solve my problem please explain in detail

Comment: Please share any example urlbto grasp more

Comment: @dghtr: See my update. I hope it helps. Or is your question more about how to implement failover in Apache?

Comment: Thanks yeah my question is of failover cache with cached data need to be available to all tomcat instances ,request you to please share an example where I can find an example

Comment: It's worth pointing-out that `memcached` is *not* distributed. There are flavors of `memcached` that can provide replication and other distributed-like features, but `memcached` is not designed to be distributed.